# Difference between REST and SOAP APIs in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

When I publish a REST API using context “/configuration” and version “v3.0”, and Production URL “myhost.com/configuration/v3.0”, and make a call to “apim.com/configuration/v3.0/codes/?count=5&id=11849&offset=0”, API Manager correctly passes the following on to my endpoint:  “myhost.com/configuration/v3.0/codes/?count=5&id=11849&offset=0”.

When I do a similar thing with a SOAP API, using context “/configuration” and version “v3.0”, and Production URL ”myhost.com/configuration/v3.0”, and make a call to “apim.com/configuration/v3.0/codes”, the API Manager pass he the following on to my endpoint:  “myhost.com/configuration/v3.0”.  This doesn’t work because “codes” was dropped.

Is there something different API Manager does with REST and SOAP?  Seems odd.

Comment: what do you mean by "When I do a similar thing with a SOAP API,".. ? How you published your API now, and how you are executing that?

Comment: I publish the SOAP API using context "/configuration" and version "v3.0", and specify a Production URL of "myhost.com/configuration/v3.0".  When I call the API, I specify "apim.com/configuration/v3.0/codes" as the URI along with the rest of my SOAP message.  But the message passed to my server from APIM is "myhost.com/configuration/v3.0", not "myhost.com/configuration/v3.0/codes".

Comment: This is different behavior than I get if I do a similar thing with a REST interface.  In that case, I publish the REST API using context "/configuration", and version "v3.0", and Production URL "myhost.com/configuration/v3.0".  When I call the API, "apim.com/configuration/v3.0/codes/?count=5&id=11849&offset=0", APIM correctly passes "myhost.com/configuration/v3.0/codes/?count=5&id=11849&offset=0" to my server.  Why does "/codes" get dropped in the SOAP case?

Comment: Hi Ratha.  This is really going to cause us issues soon - any ideas?

Comment: Hi, your commnet is not clear, what do you mean by SOAPAPI and RESTAPI.? If you publish an API via APIManager , all are REST API. DO you mean your backend service is a SOAP service and one is another RESTAPI? IF so, you can clearly provide which service/api works fine with waht type of request, and URL etc..Sorry, your terms are not clear

Comment: Hi Ratha.  Sorry I wasn't clear.  Yes, we support both SOAP and REST on our backend services.  Right now, I'm just trying to get SOAP to work.  When I publish using the context "/configuration" and version "v3.0", and specifiy a Production URL of "myhost.com/configuration.v3.0", and call the API via "apim.com/configuration/v3.0/codes", along with my SOAP message, the message passed to may server seems to be "myhost.com/configuration/v3.0", not "myhost.com/configuration/v3.0/codes".  Thus, my back end service can't process the message.

Comment: When I was playing with publishing a REST interface, the REST parameters get passed to the backend server, so I'm not sure why it's different.

Comment: Hi Ratha.  Here is a bit more info, hopefully more clear.  This is from the API Manager http_access log.  localhost:8280 - - - "POST /configuration/v3.0/codes/SOAP HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
myHost.com:8081 - - - "POST http://myhost.com:8081/configuration/v3.0 HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO".  Why doesn't the API Manager POST to myhost.com include the "/codes/SOAP"?

Comment: When you make call to an API-S(backend service is SOAP service)like `http://host/myhost.com/configuration/v3.0/codes` APIManager drops "/codes" string and for the API-R(backend service is SOAP service),It is allowed to pass that "/codes" string?
Can you post your API configurations for both cases.You can find that in the deploymnet/server/synapseconifg/api folder. In both cases, you are doing POST?

Comment: API configuration in synapseconfig is too long to post.  But it is the same in both the REST and the SOAP cases.  I have found that if I manually change the address uri in synapseconfig from myhost.com:8081/configuration/v3.0 to myhost.com:8081/configuration/v3.0/codes, it works as I want for SOAP.  It's just odd that isn't required for REST.  Is there something in API Manager that is acting differently if I have a SOAP  backend?